# read and close FD synchronization, problem

Tags: c++

I have `IPC` channel which mainly used to transfer the `CAN` data.

I'm opening the channel with `open` call as below.

```
int handle;

bool Iopen()
{
    handle = open("/dev/ipc16", O_RDWR);
    return handle != -1;
}
```

And closing the channel with `close` call as below.

```
void close()
{
      close(handle);
}
```

And there is `thread` which does blocking `read` on the channel as below.

```
void *ipcReaderFunction(void *p)
{
    IpcChannel *pIpcChannel = NULL;
    pIpcChannel = static_cast<IpcChannel*>(p);
    if(pIpcChannel == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        std::array<std::uint8_t, BUFFER_SIZE> buffer;
        const auto size = read(handle, buffer.data(), buffer.size());
        if (-1 == size) {
            if (EBADF == errno) {

               //Channel is closed
               break;
            }

            continue;
        }

        .....
        //some processing
        .....
    }
}
```

To start and stop the reader thread.

```
void startIPCReaderThread()
{
    int ret = -1;
    ret = pthread_create(&mIPCReaderThread , NULL,  &ipcReaderFunction, this);

}


void stopIPCReaderThread()
{
    int ret = -1;

    ret = pthread_join(mIPCReaderThread, NULL);
}
```

**MY Question:**

```
    if (EBADF == errno) {

       //Channel is closed
       break;
    }
```

Upon receiving some event I will be first closing the channel and then stopping the reader thread as below.

```
close();
stopIPCReaderThread();
```

Since `read` call is blocking, reader thread will not stop immediately and after some time it returns -1 with  `EBADF` errno.

Is it good idea to rely on `EBADF` errno or you want me to use `select` system call?

Comment: `stopIPCReaderThread` will not **stop** the thread. It will wait until thread is stopped.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, thread will stop once `read` returns with `EBADF` as `FD` is already closed.

Comment: We do not really want you to do anything. However, closing the handle from one thread while waiting on it in another might not be the best idea.